# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to get urls and modify them.
here is where this error occur:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    linkori = (link.get('href'))
    print 'LINKORI : %s' %linkori
    fonte1 = linkori
    fonte1 = str(fonte1.encode('utf8'))
```

My traceback:

```
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "F:\Docs\Projti\Rafael\Python Scripts\final.py", line 258, in <module>
    fonte1 = str(fonte1.encode('utf8'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I tried `.join` or something else but I always get the same error. When I print `linkori` it displays the url from `link.get` perfectly.
Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` returns `None` if there is no `href` attribute. Limit your search to `<a>` tags *with* `href` attribute only:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    linkori = link['href']
    fonte1 = linkory.encode('utf8')
```